# Roots of a given fourth degree polynomial function

Tags: polynomials, roots

**Question**

I am interested in the root of the polynomial function :

$x^4+(a+b+c+d-2)x^3+(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd-2b-2c-a-d+1)x^2
(abc+abd+acd+bcd-ab-ac-ad-2bc-bd-cd+b+c)z+
abcd-abc-bcd+bc=0$

Under the restriction that: $0<a,b,c,d<1$.

**Attempt**

I tried [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) but it went nowhere.
Does anyone have a tip for me?

Comment: what is the constant term in your polynomial? Is it $abcd−abc−bcd−ad+bc$ as in your post or ist it $abcd−abc−bcd+bc$ as assumed in both answers?

Comment: It’s like in my post. I updated it today. :-)

Comment: I rolled it back tto the previous version. If you change the coefficients now, this will invalidate the anwers that use your original coefficients. So if these coefficients are wrong then porst a new question with the correct coefficients

Answer (score 1):

Let's be optimistic and assume this polynomial has beautiful roots. We'll see if we can guess what they are.

Let $p$ be our polynomial,

$x^4+(a+b+c+d-2)x^3+(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd-2c-2b-a-d+1)x^2+(abc+abd+acd+bcd-ab-ac-2bc-bd-cd+b+c)x+(abcd-abc-bcd+bc)=p$

and $r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4$ be its four roots, then
$$p=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)$$

Compare the two forms of $p$ above. First, from its third order term,
$$\tag{1} -r_1-r_2-r_3-r_4=a+b+c+d-2.$$

Then look at the second order term:
$$\tag{2}ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd-2c-2b-a-d+1.$$

It contains all six combinations of $a,b,c,d,\ $ i.e. $\ ab,ac,ad,bc,bd,cd$, so $p$ probably looks like
$$\tag{3a}(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d),$$$$\tag{3b}(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)(x+d).$$

As $a,b,c,d$ are all positive in (1), I will vote for (3b).

The rest of the terms in (2) tell us
$$p=(x+a+k_1)(x+b+k_2)(x+c+k_3)(x+d+k_4),$$
where $k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4$ are constants which have nothing to do with $a,b,c,d$, and which, apparently, are integers.

The only number in (2) is $1$, so $k_1k_2k_3k_4=1.$

The product of four integers is $1$. Possible combinations are:

$$
  1\times1\times1\times1=1, \\
  -1\times-1\times1\times1=1, \\
  -1\times-1\times-1\times-1=1.
$$

I will leave you to decide which one is correct. The rest is to verify your answer by expanding $p$ and compare with the original one.

Comment: Thank you very much for this long comment on it. I had a mistake in my polynomial and updated it now. In this case is $k_1k_2k_3k_4=0$ or?

Comment: the constant term of your polynomial is $abcd-bcd-abc+bc$, in the OP's polynomial it is $abcd−abc−bcd−ad+bc$