# Roots of a given fourth degree polynomial function (Vieta)

Tags: polynomials, roots

**Question**

I am interested in the root of the polynomial function :

$z^4+(a+b+c+d-2)z^3+(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd-2b-2c-a-d)z^2
+(abc+abd+acd+bcd-ab-ac-ad-2bc-bd-cd-a-d+b+c)z
+abcd-abc-bcd-ad+bc$

Under the restriction that: $0<a,b,c,d<1$.

I tried Vietas formula but don’t know how to come to a decomposition

$a_0=abcd-abc-bcd-ad+bc=x_1x_2x_3x_4$

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4430519/roots-of-a-given-fourth-degree-polynomial-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Roots of a given fourth degree polynomial function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4430519/roots-of-a-given-fourth-degree-polynomial-function)

Comment: There was a comment that i should post a new question because it will be rolled to a previous version of the polynomial.

Comment: I had a mistake in the coefficients. With the previous coefficients, the solution was much easier. Now it’s a bit complicate to find a decomposition like above.

Comment: @toni_iva The equation is a [quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots), which can be solved by radicals, but the calculations are laborious. [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=16+z%5E4+-+24+z%5E2+-+20+z+-+3+%3D+0) is for example what the roots look like in the simple case $\,a=b=c=d=1/2\,$.